# Differences in getting a model

Tags: model

What is exactly the difference between:

```
$model = \JModelLegacy::getInstance('Objects', 'MyModel');
```

and

```
$model = BaseDatabaseModel::getInstance('Objects', 'MyModel');
```

Is there some performance differences? Is one of them getting removed earlier in Joomla 5?
The communcation and documentation around the Joomla Framework is bad.

I cannot do this yet so please dont suggest:

```
$model = $component->getMVCFactory()->createModel($modelName, $this->app->getName(), ['ignore_request' => true]);
```

Answer (score 1):

JModelLegacy is now just an alias of BaseDatabaseModel to support older references to JModelLegacy therefore there is no difference at all between either statement.

```
JLoader::registerAlias('JModelLegacy', '\\Joomla\\CMS\\MVC\\Model\\BaseDatabaseModel', '6.0');
```

The `createModel()` function in the LegacyFactory class, not the `createModel()` method you have shown above from MVCFactory, also uses `BaseDatabaseModel::getInstance`

Comment: OK. And will one of them dissapear in Joomla 5 first or will they both be kept for supporting deprecated stuff?

Comment: JModelLegacy will be removed in 5. It has been depreciated for some time already.